# Unable to boot windows 8 after ubuntu 12.04 installation

Tags: windows-8, ubuntu-12.04, boot

I just got my new notebook with windows 8 pre installed. After installing ubuntu 12.04 when I try to boot windows 8 it says "**Automated Recovery in Progress**" which fails afterwards and shuts down the machine stating the **partition on which windows is installed is locked.**

Actually during the ubuntu installation I merged two disk drives to one and made it as an extended partition. Then I divided the extended partition into two logical partition. One of which is blank and other is having Ubuntu installed.

I had tried to back up the data from ubuntu but I was not able to see the files of the partition containing windows 8.

Please help me to recover windows 8 or to back up the data.

Comment: How many partitions did you have, before starting the Ubuntu installation process ? which company and model notebook?

Comment: In windows I had 5 partitions: 2 were system reserve and 1 for windows 8 and 2 normal ntfs partions. I merged the 2 ntfs partitions and made them one extended partition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i figured out the problem. Windows was installed in UEFI mode and I unintentionally installed Ubuntu in Legacy mode.

Anyways Now i reinstalled both os on my machine and it is working fine now.